# Finding URL of thread when diagnosing memory in PerfView

Tags: .net, iis, memory-management, threadpool, perfview

Is there a way to determine the URL of threads making calls in PerfView? This screenshot is from GC Heap Net Mem.

[image]

Comment: you need to capture network events, too: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/debugging/windows-instructions.md#using-perfview

Comment: I see that section but where does it stay that?  Also those providers arent listed on my machine?

Comment: this * means they are not registered, they are [EventSource](http://dev.goshoom.net/2013/04/tracing-with-eventsource/) classes. All all the [network related providers](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/debugging/windows-instructions.md#systemnet-namespaces) to additional providers list

Comment: Yea I have no idea what you are talking about.  I put those and disabled everything else and doesnt give me urls.

Comment: in Events view in Perfview, in "process filter" select w3wp, search for the network events, here look for events that have the same thread ID from the gc data. look if this helps.

Comment: I did AspNetTrace/AspNetReq/Start and all the rows have the same thread ID, they arent different.

Comment: I use selfhost ASP.net core and [activate EventSource logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#event-source) and here I see SignalR [url in perfview](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/capturing-perfview-traces-for-aspnet-core-application/ba-p/342696). in add additional providers in perfview, you can select w3wp.exe to see all possible providers.

Comment: I am not using core, just .net framework 4.8